# How to fix #REF! error on COUNTIFS whenever reference spreadsheet changes

Tags: excel, countif

Is there a way to fix #REF! error on COUNTIFS formulas when the reference spreadsheet gets replaced? For instance, I receive a new master spreadsheet in a different file every month. Using COUNTIFS, I created a table to count with specific criteria based on a master spreadsheet. When I receive a new file, I make a copy of the master spreadsheet and move it to the original file with the table. The old spreadsheet is deleted. The new spreadsheet is under the same name. However, the reference in COUNTIFS breaks and #REF! error occurs.

Comment: use INDIRECT to "retain" the name as a text string.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't a change to the masterfile, can you just do a data dump and copy/paste the new data over the old? This will prevent the original sheet from being deleted and causing the reference error. Another option would be to copy/paste the formulas over to the new mastersheet so the formulas are preserved.